# importing Text gives error

Tags: react-native

Im trying to work with text and im following a tutorial that says in order to work with text just type this

```
var React = require('react');
var Text = React.Text;
```

and then you can use it and it works with him

but with me it did not work and gives error says

```
element type is invalid expected a string
```

and in order to make it work i wrote

```
import {Text} from 'react-native';
```

so why is this difference?

i think that the first one familiar to me than the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching in two different places. In the first attempt you are looking inside the `react` package, which is the same one you would use for React on the web. Of course, it does not make much sense having a React Native-specific component in that package, and that is the reason why you are not finding it. In the second one, you are querying a completely different package, the `react-native` one, which does have the element you are looking for.

Comment: that means it is transfered from one package to another in different version

Comment: No, the packages for React and React Native are completely independent. I don't think `Text` was ever in the package for React. What exactly do you mean by 'transferred'?